# In F#, how is an interface cast within a lambda expression?

Tags: interface, f#

I'm finding the concept of interfaces in F# to be significantly different then C#.

```
The following code in F# works correctly:

type MyVisit = {
        lastname : string
        firstname : string
        birthdate : DateTime
        appointment_time : DateTime
        service_time : DateTime
        posting_time : DateTime
        chart_number : int
    }

module FsNetwork =
    let context = Wsdl1.GetBasicHttpBinding_IMedicalService()
    let GetScheduleAsync (tableDate : DateTime) =
        async {
            let! data = context.GetOfficeScheduleAsync(tableDate) |> Async.AwaitTask
            return data |> Seq.map(fun q -> {
                MyVisit.lastname = q.lastname
                firstname = q.firstname
                birthdate = q.birthdate
                appointmentTime = q.appointment_time
                tservice = q.service_time
                posting_time = q.posting_time
                chart_number = q.chart_number
                })                  
        }
       |> Async.StartAsTask
```

However, when implementing the interface of:

```
type IVisit = 
    abstract member lastname: string with get
    abstract member firstname: string with get
    abstract member mi: string with get
    abstract member birthdate: Nullable<DateTime> with get
    abstract member appointmentTime : System.Nullable<DateTime> with get
    abstract member tservice : System.Nullable<DateTime> with get
    abstract member postingTime : System.Nullable<DateTime> with get
    abstract member chartNumber : System.Nullable<int> with get

type Visit = 
    interface IVisit with 
        member this.lastname = "lastname"
        member this.firstname = "FirstName"
        member this.mi = "mi"
        member this.birthdate = Nullable(DateTime(2020, 1, 1))
        member this.appointmentTime = Nullable(DateTime(2020, 1, 1)) 
        member this.tservice = Nullable(DateTime(2020, 1, 1)) 
        member this.postingTime = Nullable(DateTime(2020, 1, 1)) 
        member this.chartNumber = Nullable(0)
```

The lambda now fails with
*The type 'Visit' does not define the field, constructor or member 'lastname'*

```
module FsNetwork =
    let context = Wsdl1.GetBasicHttpBinding_IMedicalService()
    let GetScheduleAsync (tableDate : DateTime) =
        async {
            let! data = context.GetOfficeScheduleAsync(tableDate) |> Async.AwaitTask
            return data |> Seq.map(fun q -> {
                Visit.lastname = q.lastname
                firstname = q.firstname
                birthdate = q.birthdate
                appointmentTime = q.appointment_time
                tservice = q.service_time
                posting_time = q.posting_time
                chart_number = q.chart_number
                })                  
        }
       |> Async.StartAsTask
```

Attempting to cast 'Visit' with Visit:>IVisit.lastname =..., or Visit:#IVisit.lastname =... also fail. I'm sure its simple, how is this done?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: to create a value using a interface you must use object expression syntax, or implement a class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/object-expressions), what you've done is try to create a record of type "Visit", and it isnt a record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are using in your second code snippet is a snippet for record initialization. However, you want to create an instance of an interface instead.

You could do this by creating a class - but your class definition is not quite that yet, because it does not have a constructor. So, you would need something along the lines:

```
type Visit(first:string, last:string) = 
  interface IVisit with
    member x.first = first
    member x.last = last
```

This gets quite cumbersome, so I would instead use another F# feature, anonymous object expression, which lets you create an instance of an interface without a class:

```
 { new IVisit with 
    member x.first = "Yadda"
    member x.last = "Yadda" }
```

Using this, your code would look something like:

```
let context = Wsdl1.GetBasicHttpBinding_IMedicalService()
let GetScheduleAsync (tableDate : DateTime) =
    async {
        let data = context.GetOfficeScheduleAsync(tableDate) |> Async.AwaitTask
        return data |> Seq.map(fun q -> 
          { new IVisit with 
            member this.mi = "??"
            member this.lastname = q.lastname
            member this.firstname = q.firstname
            member this.birthdate = q.birthdate
            member this.appointmentTime = q.appointment_time
            member this.tservice = q.service_time
            member this.postingTime = q.posting_time
            member this.chartNumber = q.chart_number })                  
    }
   |> Async.StartAsTask
```

That said, I don't really see why you need an interface here, rather than ordinary F# record. Even if you are going to be using this library from C#, a record will look just like a normal class.

Comment: My C# code uses interfaces as DI and such as List<IVisit>(). My thinking was that to statisfy List<IVisit>() in C#, the F# record had to implement IVisit. Am I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @AlanWayne Yeah, that's right - but I don't see why you would need dependency injection for a simple record type. The record is just storing data and it's generated by the compiler, so it's correct and I doubt you'll ever want to replace it with another implementation...

Comment: In the C# code, I have multiple different record types that have more fields then are expressed with IVisit. However, some of my methods only depend on the fields within IVisit. Hence, my allowing the different types to share the common IVisit interface, I can apply the same methods to different structures. In either event, can I use the anonymous object to statisfy the C# List<IVisit>? Or how would you suggest doing this?  Thanks.

Comment: @AlanWayne You could put a `Visit` inside another record: `type SomeType = { FirstVisit : Visit; OtherInfo : OtherInfo }`. Interfaces feel quite heavyweight for just grouping bits of data.